# accept() returning invalid argument

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

Learning about TCP connections. Can anyone see why my accept() call is erroring with an "invalid argument"? I can't see what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int sockfd, newfd;

    struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;
    unsigned int recvLen;
    socklen_t addr_size;

    fd_set read_set;
    struct timeval tv;

    // initialize the fd set
    FD_ZERO(&read_set);

    // prepare the address struct for the first client
    bzero(&clientAddr,sizeof(clientAddr));                          //zero the struct
    clientAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                              //address family (ipv4)
    clientAddr.sin_port = htons(6001);  //sets port to network byte order
    clientAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr_size = sizeof(clientAddr);

    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Cannot create socket for client 0.\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Terminating program\n\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Socket established for client 0\n");
    }

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, sizeof(clientAddr)) < 0) {
        fprintf (stdout, "Binding failed for client 0\n\n");
        perror("bind failed");
        exit (1);
    } else {
        fprintf (stdout, "Binding successful for client 0\n");
    }

    // ERROR HAPPENS ON THE NEXT LINE
    if ((newfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, &addr_size)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Error accepting inbound data from client 0\n");
        perror(" accept() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "\tSuccessfully accepted inbound connection from client 0\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A call to `listen` is missing after `bind` before `accept`.

Answer (score 0):

I would initialize addr_size to sizeof(clientAddr) and clear clientAddr

Comment: If you dont initialize addr_size to sizeof(clinetAddr) before calling accept, kernel would not know that the address reference passed as argument contains the required space for it to copy the address from where the connection has come. I hope this explains-           From man page of  accept-  
The addrlen argument is a value-result
       argument: it should initially contain the size of the structure pointed to by addr